# Получить значение из TextBox

Tags: asp.net

Как получить значение из TextBox, зная его ID?
TextBox-ы создаются динамически, в процессе создания им присваивается id

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="container" runat="server" />
```

SERVER:

```
   //добавление
   var id = "txtID";
   container.Controls.Add(new TextBox {ID = id});

   ...

   //Получение
   var txt = container.FindControl(id) as TextBox;
   if (txt != null)
   {
      var txtValue = txt.Text;
   }
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но программа не понимает код....выдает ошибку....
поясню: в создаваемые textBox-ы записываются данные, которые необходимо сохранить в БД.... не получается "прочитать" то, что записано в textBox

Comment: Вы контейнер правильно указали? Под контейнером понимается контрол-контейнер, в который вы добавляете текстбоксы. Это может быть Page, div и тд. Вместо слова Container нужно указать его ID - возможно я сразу не понятно указал.

Comment: И еще любопытно как вы добавляете текстбоксы динамически и в какой момент жизненного цикла страницы?

Comment: попробую переделать. Спасибо! TextBox-ы добавляю в Placeholder в Page_Load

Comment: поставьте вместо container идентификатор this, тогда поиск текстбокса будет выполняться на всей странице

Comment: советую не использовать Page_Load вместо него делайте override метода OnLoad

Comment: Любопытно ваше виденье, почему такой последний совет? Какие аргументы в пользу него? С вопросом это не связано - мне для себя интересно.

Comment: И по поводу контейнера совет тоже вызывает сомнения, так как не факт, что контрол будет в таком случае найден!